# What forum software does Vimeo use?

Tags: forum

What forum software does **[Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/forum%3avimeo_projects)** use?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about the underlying technology of a web application.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is built in house by Vimeo but the only way top be certain would be to contact them directly.

Comment: Totally agree.. even if they started with something else.. I think now it's completely custom made..!

Comment: @Lipis - Yep, my thoughts exactly.  There is a bit of MooTools in there but it could literally be any sort of hybrid concoction

Comment: If they can serve millions of videos to millions of people without any issues... I'm pretty sure they can build their own forum with their very specific needs..! :)

Answer (score 1):

According to Daniel Hayek of Vimeo, they [wrote it from scratch](http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:16873). So yeah, it's custom built, and not based any of the (then/now) existing forum applications.